# PHP set_include_path

Tags: php, path, include, require

I have a MainClass.php file with other .php files in the same directory. I noticed that I can include other .php files inside this file by using:

`require "file.php";`

and it seems to load them even if I don't specify the full path to the script. Will this work on any server setup? Or do I have to manually add the full path or change the include path:

`set_include_path(dirname(__FILE__));`

before the require statements

?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By default, PHP's include path includes `.`. This represents the current working directory (CWD) which is why your includes are working.

I think it best to play it safe and use an explicit include path or absolute paths wherever possible as indicated in your question.

A popular method is

```
set_include_path(implode(PATH_SEPARATOR, array(
    $applicationIncludePath,
    get_include_path()
));
```

Comment: by default? does that mean that the server admin can change this setting?

Comment: @Emm That's correct. The include path does not need to include `.` and may be configured without it